# Is it possible to reconfigure FirebaseApp with different FirebaseOptions at runtime, to log Analytics events?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

I tried deleting the default app and reconfiguring it, but the Analytics events are still being sent to the first configuration's database.

```
guard let app = FirebaseApp.app() else {
    return
}

app.delete { (success) in
    let options = self.configurationOptions()

    FirebaseApp.configure(options: options)
}
```

The DebugView of configuration A is still showing events after switching to configuration B.

**Info:**

- I can confirm the `FirebaseOptions` were different when logging events with configuration A and B by inspecting the variable `FirebaseApp.app()?.options.googleAppID` on `lldb` console;
- I'm using the latest versions of Firebase pods;
- I'm not using `GoogleService-Info.plist` file;
- The code mentioned above is executed with no errors;

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Analytics can only be configured once because the report could be incorrect at different time. You cannot delete the app and configure with a different options. I'd recommend to only use one app for Analytics.